# Solution of $\cos (x) -1=\frac{2}{\cos (x)}$?

Tags: trigonometry

What is solution of $\cos (x) -1=\frac{2}{\cos (x)}$ in the interval $0< x <2 \pi$ ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you thought about how you might solve it?

Comment: Can you also check that the interval is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This implies $$\cos(x)(\cos(x)-1)=2$$
but $$-1\le \cos(x) \le 1$$ and $$-2\le \cos(x)-1 \le 0$$
So the product is only equal to $2$ when $\cos(x)=-1$ and $\cos(x)-1=-2$ which is again, $\cos(x)=-1$. This means $$x=\pi$$ and it is the only solution (and it is a double root).

Answer (score 4):

$$ \cos x - 1 = \frac{2}{\cos x}$$

Multiply both sides by $\cos x$

$$ \cos^2 x - \cos x - 2 = 0$$

Factorise the above equation:

$$ (\cos x - 2)(\cos x +1 ) = 0$$

Can you take it from here? Note the intervals

Answer (score 2):

In *absolute value*, the LHS is $\leq 2$, and the RHS is $\geq 2$, so they both have to be exactly $2$.

Now, the LHS is $\leq0$, so, considering also the sign, both sides must be exactly $-2$, and this happens when, and only when, $\cos x=-1$, or $x=(2k+1)\pi$.

In $]0,2\pi[$, the only possible value is $x=\pi$.

Comment: Nice observation. Alternatively you can say $LHS\in [-2,0]$ and $RHS\notin (-2,2)$, hence both are $-2$.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$1-\cos x=2\sin^2\frac x2$$
the equation becomes
$$\sin^2\frac x2\cos x=-1$$
which gives
$$\cos x=-1$$
and finally
$$x=\pi$$